# Creating a function in the postgresql database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, postgresql, heroku, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function on my Heroku database. 
I'll eventually tie it to a trigger.

I've seen the error all over, but I can't seem to see a way around it.

The error I get is...

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  language "plpgsql" does not exist
```

What I'm reading is that I can't create triggers or functions on heroku. Unless I go with the shared_database, which is not an option. My app is already multi-tenanted, and makes use of it's own schemas.

I attempted to create the language as suggested, but that is denied.

Question: Am I reading things right, can one create functions in postgesql on heroku?

Question: If one can make functions in the database, then does anyone know how?

Comment: You're using the shared database, right? I have lots of functions and triggers defined in a dedicated Heroku database.

Comment: turns out I am indeed using the shared. Most confusing, because I am able to create different schemas.. Or I was in the past.

Answer (score 5):

Since PostgreSQL 9.0 the procedural language PL/pgSQL is pre-installed. On earlier versions you have to run:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

once per database. Heroku shared may still be PostgreSQL 8.3. [More in the fine manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createlanguage.html)

However, the old "shared" plan does not allow plpgsql, as far as I have heard (don't use it myself). There is a [new plan with PostgreSQL 9.1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-shared-postgresql) , supporting plpgsql, though.

Comment: I can confirm the basic heroku plan does not let you do "CREATE language plpgsql"

Comment: @anka: Double quotes are not needed for `plpgsql` here. Try the fine manual.